# TikZ picture positioning in landscape

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, automata

I wrote a large game tree (using *automata* package) and need to display it in landscape mode. I already tried to use both *textpos* and *geometry* (newgeometry command) packages but without any positive results. I need to shift the picture to the left so the right part of the game tree displays properly. Any suggestions? Also if there is a way to fit it in portrait mode it would be even better. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textpos} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,positioning,shadows,arrows,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                semithick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill,draw=none,green,text=white,circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{accepting}=[circle split, draw,text=black,inner sep=0.08cm]
\tikzstyle{initial}=[red,text=white]
\node[state,initial]  (N0) {Nature};
\node[state]   (N1) [below left of=N0,xshift=-5cm]  {Nature};
\node[state]   (F1) [below left of=N1]  {R\&G};
\node[state]   (K1) [below right of=N1] {R\&G};
\node[state]   (FS1) [below left of=F1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (FN1) [above left of=F1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[state]        (KS1) [below right of=K1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (KN1) [above right of=K1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSC1) [below left of=FS1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSN1) [above left of=FS1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSC1) [below right of=KS1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSN1) [above right of=KS1] {\phantom{1}};

\path(N1) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F1) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K1);
\path(F1) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN1);
\path(K1) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN1);
\path(FS1) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN1);
\path(KS1) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN1);
\path(K1) edge[thick,dotted,-](F1);

 \node[state]   (N)[below right of=N0,xshift=5cm]  {Nature};
 \node[state]    (F) [below left of=N]  {R\&G};
 \node[state]    (K) [below right of=N] {R\&G};
 \node[state]    (FS) [below left of=F]  {H};
 \node[accepting]    (FN) [above left of=F] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[state]    (KS) [below right of=K]  {H};
 \node[accepting]     (KN) [above right of=K] {\phantom{1}};
  \node[accepting]    (FSC) [below left of=FS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (FSN) [above left of=FS] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (KSC) [below right of=KS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]     (KSN) [above right of=KS] {\phantom{1}};

 \path(N) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K);
 \path(F) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN);
 \path(K) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN);
 \path(FS) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN);
 \path(KS) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN);
 \path(K) edge[thick,dotted,-](F);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}`, loading all the required packages (but only the required ones), etc. Otherwise, people who want to help you have to do it themselves. Help them help you :)

Comment: Could you please pass the option `paperheight=35cm` to geometry package: `\usepackage[paperwidth=35cm]{geometry}` and see how it looks.

Comment: Thanks Kan: that works and it is also a nice hack to use for future projects.

Comment: You can use `current page.xxx` to specify coordinates of nodes, which is useful for page-based alignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution without `\resizebox` because with this macro, the text is resized. I try to use landscape environment like you.
The problem is to know if you need to use this tree in a big document or alone.

1) `parindent=0pt`  to extra horizontal space.

2) `\eject\null` try to put the box on a new page in vertical mode; now it's possible to use `\vfill` around the box.

3) `\hspace*{-4cm}` i don't know exactly what is the layout used by the class exam, so I search by hand a good dimension to center the box without the left margin.

4) I reduced a little `node distance` here 2.5cm instead of 2.8cm perhaps it's possible to reduce again but you need in this case change the place of some texts.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,positioning,shadows,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\newlength\Textht
\setlength\Textht{\textheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\parindent=0pt
\eject\null
\vfill
\hspace*{-4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
                semithick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill,draw=none,green,text=white,circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{accepting}=[circle split, draw,text=black,inner sep=0.08cm]
\tikzstyle{initial}=[red,text=white]
\node[state,initial]  (N0) {Nature};
\node[state]        (N1)   [below left  of=N0,xshift=-5cm]  {Nature};
\node[state]        (F1)   [below left  of=N1]  {R\&G};
\node[state]        (K1)   [below right of=N1]  {R\&G};
\node[state]        (FS1)  [below left  of=F1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (FN1)  [above left  of=F1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[state]        (KS1)  [below right of=K1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (KN1)  [above right of=K1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSC1) [below left  of=FS1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSN1) [above left  of=FS1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSC1) [below right of=KS1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSN1) [above right of=KS1] {\phantom{1}};

\path(N1) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F1) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K1);
\path(F1) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN1);
\path(K1) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN1);
\path(FS1) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN1);
\path(KS1) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN1);
\path(K1) edge[thick,dotted,-](F1);

 \node[state]        (N)   [below right of=N0,xshift=5cm]  {Nature};
 \node[state]        (F)   [below left  of=N]  {R\&G};
 \node[state]        (K)   [below right of=N] {R\&G};
 \node[state]        (FS)  [below left  of=F]  {H};
 \node[accepting]    (FN)  [above left  of=F] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[state]        (KS)  [below right of=K]  {H};
 \node[accepting]    (KN)  [above right of=K] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (FSC) [below left  of=FS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (FSN) [above left  of=FS] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (KSC) [below right of=KS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (KSN) [above right of=KS] {\phantom{1}};

 \path(N) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K);
 \path(F) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN);
 \path(K) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN);
 \path(FS) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN);
 \path(KS) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN);
 \path(K) edge[thick,dotted,-](F);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
\vfill
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package; since in landscape mode the width and the height get swapped you need to use the original `\textheight` as the new width for the resizing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,positioning,shadows,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\newlength\Textht
\setlength\Textht{\textheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\null\vfill

\noindent\resizebox{\Textht}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                semithick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill,draw=none,green,text=white,circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{accepting}=[circle split, draw,text=black,inner sep=0.08cm]
\tikzstyle{initial}=[red,text=white]
\node[state,initial]  (N0) {Nature};
\node[state]   (N1) [below left of=N0,xshift=-5cm]  {Nature};
\node[state]   (F1) [below left of=N1]  {R\&G};
\node[state]   (K1) [below right of=N1] {R\&G};
\node[state]   (FS1) [below left of=F1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (FN1) [above left of=F1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[state]        (KS1) [below right of=K1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (KN1) [above right of=K1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSC1) [below left of=FS1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSN1) [above left of=FS1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSC1) [below right of=KS1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSN1) [above right of=KS1] {\phantom{1}};

\path(N1) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F1) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K1);
\path(F1) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN1);
\path(K1) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN1);
\path(FS1) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN1);
\path(KS1) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN1);
\path(K1) edge[thick,dotted,-](F1);

 \node[state]   (N)[below right of=N0,xshift=5cm]  {Nature};
 \node[state]    (F) [below left of=N]  {R\&G};
 \node[state]    (K) [below right of=N] {R\&G};
 \node[state]    (FS) [below left of=F]  {H};
 \node[accepting]    (FN) [above left of=F] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[state]    (KS) [below right of=K]  {H};
 \node[accepting]     (KN) [above right of=K] {\phantom{1}};
  \node[accepting]    (FSC) [below left of=FS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (FSN) [above left of=FS] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (KSC) [below right of=KS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]     (KSN) [above right of=KS] {\phantom{1}};

 \path(N) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K);
 \path(F) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN);
 \path(K) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN);
 \path(FS) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN);
 \path(KS) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN);
 \path(K) edge[thick,dotted,-](F);

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\vfill
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also used some `\vfill` commands to vertically center the `tikzpicture`, but those are optional. Notice also that, since you are loading `tikz`, there's no need to explicitly load `pgf`.

The same command can be used to resize your tree in portrait mode:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,positioning,shadows,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                semithick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill,draw=none,green,text=white,circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{accepting}=[circle split, draw,text=black,inner sep=0.08cm]
\tikzstyle{initial}=[red,text=white]
\node[state,initial]  (N0) {Nature};
\node[state]   (N1) [below left of=N0,xshift=-5cm]  {Nature};
\node[state]   (F1) [below left of=N1]  {R\&G};
\node[state]   (K1) [below right of=N1] {R\&G};
\node[state]   (FS1) [below left of=F1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (FN1) [above left of=F1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[state]        (KS1) [below right of=K1]  {H};
\node[accepting]    (KN1) [above right of=K1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSC1) [below left of=FS1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (FSN1) [above left of=FS1] {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSC1) [below right of=KS1]  {\phantom{1}};
\node[accepting]    (KSN1) [above right of=KS1] {\phantom{1}};

\path(N1) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F1) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K1);
\path(F1) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN1);
\path(K1) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN1);
\path(FS1) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC1) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN1);
\path(KS1) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC1) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN1);
\path(K1) edge[thick,dotted,-](F1);

 \node[state]   (N)[below right of=N0,xshift=5cm]  {Nature};
 \node[state]    (F) [below left of=N]  {R\&G};
 \node[state]    (K) [below right of=N] {R\&G};
 \node[state]    (FS) [below left of=F]  {H};
 \node[accepting]    (FN) [above left of=F] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[state]    (KS) [below right of=K]  {H};
 \node[accepting]     (KN) [above right of=K] {\phantom{1}};
  \node[accepting]    (FSC) [below left of=FS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (FSN) [above left of=FS] {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]    (KSC) [below right of=KS]  {\phantom{1}};
 \node[accepting]     (KSN) [above right of=KS] {\phantom{1}};

 \path(N) edge node[ above left, pos=.20]{feed Hamlet}  node[ below right, pos=.30]{0} (F) 
edge node[above right, pos=.20]{kill Hamlet} node[below left, pos=.30]{1} (K);
 \path(F) edge node[above left,pos=.5]{escort} (FS) edge node[ left]{don't}(FN);
 \path(K) edge node[above right,pos=.5]{escort} (KS) edge node[ right]{don't}(KN);
 \path(FS) edge node[above left]{change} (FSC) edge node[ left]{don't}(FSN);
 \path(KS) edge node[above right]{change} (KSC) edge node[ right]{don't}(KSN);
 \path(K) edge[thick,dotted,-](F);

\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]